# Unrecognised emulation mode: i386pep when linking x64 asm on Windows 10

Tags: windows, gcc, assembly, x86-64, ld

I've tried to compile a "hello world" assembly program using nasm and gcc.
I was able to run it succesfully using 32bit assemblation and linking:

```
nasm -fwin32 hello.asm
gcc hello.obj
```

However, when trying to use x64:

```
nasm -fwin64 hello.asm
gcc -m64 hello.obj
```

i get:

> ld.exe: unrecognised emulation mode: i386pep Supported emulations: i386pe

How can I update the linker for different emulations?
The problem persist on both mingw32 & 64.

Comment: You need to get a 64-bit version of your compiler and tool chain. At a minimum the LD program you are using is one that only supports 32-bit.

Comment: Are you sure you're linking with the same MinGW64 that can make 64-bit executables?  "emulations" are what GNU `ld` calls "targets", i.e. executable formats, and it's saying it doesn't support 64-bit.

Comment: I am using 
`gcc version 8.1.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`
with default ld `GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.30`

Comment: That's an i686 (32-bit) compiler built *by* a 64-bit compiler.  It targets 32-bit only.

Comment: Thank you, just downloaded tdm64. Not sure if I can mark a comment as a correct answer, tho.

Comment: No problems here with `i686-win32-sjlj-rev0 GCC 8.1.0` building 64-bit executables for Win10 under 32.-bit-WinXP.

Comment: Just realized MinGW-W64 does have an option to specify x86_64 architecture during installation process. Not sure why i686 is selected by default.